# Merge these scripts together to iterate over more algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

[image]I have 4 types of data.
each one has been pre-processed using:

x1,y1=Standardisation

x2,y2=Normalisation

x3,y3=Rescale

and one is completely unprocessed (x,y).

I have applied logistic regression to each like this:

```
#Building Logistic Regression model on the UNPROCESSED DATA

from sklearn.metrics import  accuracy_score

lr_model = LogisticRegression()
lr_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
lr_predict = lr_model.predict(x_test)

print('Logistic Regression - ',accuracy_score(lr_predict,y_test))
```

```
#Building Logistic Regression model on the NORMALISED DATA
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr_norm = LogisticRegression()
lr_norm.fit(x1_train, y1_train)
y_pred = lr_norm.predict(x1_test)
print("Accuracy of logistic regression on test set with Rescaled features: {:.2f}".format(lr_norm.score(x1_test, y1_test)))
```

and so on...

I want to make one graph, not sure which, that best represents the performance through its accuracy score, or whatever else there may be... but of the other models I wish to test down below:

```
svm_model = SVC(kernel='linear')
svm_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
svc_predict = svm_model.predict(x_test)

print('SVM - ',accuracy_score(svc_predict,y_test))
print('\t\t\t\tTRAIN DATA\n')
print(classification_report(y_train, svm_model.predict(x_train), target_names=encoder.inverse_transform([0,1,2])))
print('\n')
print('\t\t\t\tTEST DATA\n')
print(classification_report(y_test, svm_model.predict(x_test), target_names=encoder.inverse_transform([0,1,2])))
```

```
nb_model = GaussianNB()
nb_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
nb_predict = nb_model.predict(x_test)

print('Naive bayes - ',accuracy_score(nb_predict,y_test))
```

```
dt_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3)
dt_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
dt_predict = dt_model.predict(x_test)

print('Decision Tree - ',accuracy_score(dt_predict,y_test))
```

```
rfc_model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3)
rfc_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
rfc_predict = rfc_model.predict(x_test)

print('Random Forest - ',accuracy_score(rfc_predict,y_test))
```

```
knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn_model.fit(x_train,y_train)
knn_predict = knn_model.predict(x_test)

print('knn - ',accuracy_score(knn_predict,y_test))
```

Hope this makes sense..

```
#preprare data
pre_processing=[('NOT PROCESSED', None)]
pre_processing.append(('RESCALED', MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))))
pre_processing.append(('STANDARDIZED', StandardScaler()))
pre_processing.append(('NORMALIZED', Normalizer()))

# prepare models
models = []
models.append(( 'LR'   , LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000)))
models.append(( 'LDA'  , LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(( 'KNN'  , KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(( 'CART' , DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(( 'NB'   , GaussianNB()))
models.append(( 'SVM'  , SVC(probability=True)))
results = []
names = []
higher_acc=0
standard=0
best_model=''
for process in pre_processing:
    globals()['df_'+process[0]] = pd.DataFrame(index=None, columns=None)
    for algo in models:
        estimators = [process,algo]
        model = Pipeline(estimators)
        ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
        names.append(algo[0])
        for scoring in performance_metrix:
            cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=ss, scoring=scoring)
            globals()['df_'+process[0]].loc[algo[0],scoring]= '%s\u00B1%s'%(round(cv_results.mean()*100.0,2),round(cv_results.std()*100.0,2))
            if performance_metrix.index(scoring)==0:
                results.append(cv_results)
            if cv_results.mean()*100.0 > higher_acc:
                higher_acc=cv_results.mean()*100.0
                standard=cv_results.std()*100.0
                best_model=process[0], algo[0]
                
            elif cv_results.mean()*100.0 == higher_acc:
                if cv_results.std()*100.0 < standard:
                    higher_acc=cv_results.mean()*100.0
                    best_model=process[0], algo[0]
            
                    
            
    print('For %s data we produced:\n\n'%(process[0]),globals()['df_'+process[0]],'\n\n')

    # boxplot algorithm comparison
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Algorithms accuracy comparison for %s data'%(process[0]))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    pyplot.boxplot(results[:len(models)])
    ax.set_xticklabels(names)
    pyplot.show()

# Create a pipeline that standardizes the data then creates a model
print("The overall best performance was the one obtained with %s data, using %s algorithm. \nIt's Accuracy resulted to be %s with a standard deviation of %s" %(best_model[0],best_model[1],round(higher_acc,2),round(standard,2)))
```

Comment: Cant you just store the accuracy results and plot them?

Comment: Yes, I could, but my script is going to be very long and redundant, something I think a for loop could solve, but I am not too sure

Comment: Currently I have 7 blocks, just for logistic regression, I would need to do that for each of these: 
Decision tree
KNN
SVM
Naive Bayes Classification
Random forest
XGBoost
LightGBM

Comment: Just to clarify, you run each model on four sets of data and in turn, generate four accuracy results per model. Do you want to plot the accuracy results for all the models on a single plot?

Comment: Correct, correct. I would like to plot them, yes... I will upload a photo of it in the post!

Comment: Can you share the code for generating this plot?

Comment: Please describe the labels and the axes of the plot you introduced. Also, consider that when you have a long script/program with redundancies, it's probably time to refactor it into separate methods/functions to perform those redundant tasks.

Comment: Yes @pjs, that would probably be ideal. The x axis is the algorithm, and the y axis is the accuracy score.

Comment: @Amer, yes, it is on GitHub, it is already done actually, but I dont want to replicate someone else's work. I will update the post with it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
datasets = {
    "Unprocessed": (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test),
    "Standardisation": (x1_train, x1_test, y1_train, y1_test),
    "Normalisation": (x2_train, x2_test, y2_train, y2_test),
    "Rescale": (x3_train, x3_test, y3_train, y3_test),
}

models = {
    "Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression(),
    "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3),
    "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3)
}

def evaluate_model(model, dataset):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = data
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    pred = model.predict(x_test)
    return accuracy_score(pred, y_test)


model_scores_for_datasets = {}
for dataset_name, dataset in datasets.items():
    dataset_scores = {}
    
    for model_name, model in models.items():
        model_score = evaluate_model(model, dataset)
        dataset_scores[model_name] = model_score
        
    model_scores_for_datasets[dataset_name] = dataset_scores
```

Here, `model_scores_for_datasets` will contain the accuracy results for every dataset for each model and will look something like:

```py
{
    "Unprocessed" :
        {
            "Logistic Regression" : 10,
            "Decision Tree": 5,
            "Random Forest": 20
        },
    "Standardisation" :
        {
            "Logistic Regression" : 10,
            "Decision Tree": 5,
            "Random Forest": 20
        },
    "Normalisation" :
        {
            "Logistic Regression" : 10,
            "Decision Tree": 5,
            "Random Forest": 20
        },
    "Rescale" :
        {
            "Logistic Regression" : 10,
            "Decision Tree": 5,
            "Random Forest": 20
        },
}
```

You now have the results for each dataset and can create your required plots. Something along these line:

```py
for dataset_name, scores in model_scores_for_datasets.items():
    # For example:
    # dataset_name will be "Unprocessed"
    # scores will be a dict like so:
    # {
        #     "Logistic Regression" : 10,
        #     "Decision Tree": 5,
        #     "Random Forest": 20
    # }
    generate_plot(dataset_name scores)
```

Of course, you need to figure out the `generate_plot` function. Hope this helps and gives you some idea.

Comment: Let me try this out now, thank you kindly. will report back in a bit

Comment: I am having an issue I guess with the header, it is saying that "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SepalLengthCm'" but I think the header is needed for this..

Comment: Where is the error occuring?

Comment: I can paste the entire error code. It is long, so Ill make a new comment.

Comment: Just posted! @Amer